# Configure TLS on ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: java, activemq-artemis

I can't get TLS to work on ActiveMQ Artemis.

I've followed this steps to create truststore and keystore

```
# Create a broker key and cert - import the keypair and cert into the broker keystore
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout broker_keypair.pem -x509 -days 65000 -out broker_cert.pem
openssl pkcs12 -inkey broker_keypair.pem -in broker_cert.pem -export -out broker_ks.p12

# Create a client key and cert - import the keypair and cert into the client keystore
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout client_keypair.pem -x509 -days 65000 -out client_cert.pem
openssl pkcs12 -inkey client_keypair.pem -in client_cert.pem -export -out client_ks.p12

# Create a truststore for the broker, and import the client's certificate. This establishes that the broker "trusts" the client:
keytool -import -alias client -keystore broker_ts.p12 -file client_cert.pem -deststoretype pkcs12

# Create a truststore for the client, and import the broker's certificate. This establishes that the client "trusts" the broker:
keytool -import -alias broker -keystore client_ts.p12 -file broker_cert.pem -deststoretype pkcs12
```

From official example i configure the **netty ssl** adding this acceptor

```xml
<acceptor name="netty-acceptor">tcp://localhost:61616</acceptor>
<acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://0.0.0.0:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true;sslEnabled=true;keyStorePath=/home/nik/Scrivania/javaCert3/broker_ks.p12;keyStorePassword=qwerty;trustStorePath=/home/nik/Scrivania/javaCert3/broker_ts.p12;trustStorePassword=qwerty;needClientAuth=true</acceptor>
```

My `broker.xml` is

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
-->

<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
               xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">

   <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">

      <name>0.0.0.0</name>


      <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>

      <!-- this could be ASYNCIO, MAPPED, NIO
           ASYNCIO: Linux Libaio
           MAPPED: mmap files
           NIO: Plain Java Files
       -->
      <journal-type>NIO</journal-type>

      <paging-directory>data/paging</paging-directory>

      <bindings-directory>data/bindings</bindings-directory>

      <journal-directory>data/journal</journal-directory>

      <large-messages-directory>data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>

      <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>

      <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>

      <journal-pool-files>10</journal-pool-files>

      <journal-device-block-size>4096</journal-device-block-size>

      <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>

      <!--
       This value was determined through a calculation.
       Your system could perform 0,09 writes per millisecond
       on the current journal configuration.
       That translates as a sync write every 11320000 nanoseconds.

       Note: If you specify 0 the system will perform writes directly to the disk.
             We recommend this to be 0 if you are using journalType=MAPPED and journal-datasync=false.
      -->
      <journal-buffer-timeout>11320000</journal-buffer-timeout>


      <!--
        When using ASYNCIO, this will determine the writing queue depth for libaio.
       -->
      <journal-max-io>1</journal-max-io>
      <!--
        You can verify the network health of a particular NIC by specifying the <network-check-NIC> element.
         <network-check-NIC>theNicName</network-check-NIC>
        -->

      <!--
        Use this to use an HTTP server to validate the network
         <network-check-URL-list>http://www.apache.org</network-check-URL-list> -->

      <!-- <network-check-period>10000</network-check-period> -->
      <!-- <network-check-timeout>1000</network-check-timeout> -->

      <!-- this is a comma separated list, no spaces, just DNS or IPs
           it should accept IPV6

           Warning: Make sure you understand your network topology as this is meant to validate if your network is valid.
                    Using IPs that could eventually disappear or be partially visible may defeat the purpose.
                    You can use a list of multiple IPs, and if any successful ping will make the server OK to continue running -->
      <!-- <network-check-list>10.0.0.1</network-check-list> -->

      <!-- use this to customize the ping used for ipv4 addresses -->
      <!-- <network-check-ping-command>ping -c 1 -t %d %s</network-check-ping-command> -->

      <!-- use this to customize the ping used for ipv6 addresses -->
      <!-- <network-check-ping6-command>ping6 -c 1 %2$s</network-check-ping6-command> -->




      <!-- how often we are looking for how many bytes are being used on the disk in ms -->
      <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>

      <!-- once the disk hits this limit the system will block, or close the connection in certain protocols
           that won't support flow control. -->
      <max-disk-usage>90</max-disk-usage>

      <!-- should the broker detect dead locks and other issues -->
      <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>

      <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>

      <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>

      <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>

      <!-- the system will enter into page mode once you hit this limit.
           This is an estimate in bytes of how much the messages are using in memory

            The system will use half of the available memory (-Xmx) by default for the global-max-size.
            You may specify a different value here if you need to customize it to your needs.

            <global-max-size>100Mb</global-max-size>

      -->
<!--
      <connectors>
         <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?sslEnabled=true;keyStorePath=client_ks.p12;keyStorePassword=qwerty;trustStorePath=client_ts.p12;trustStorePassword=qwerty</connector>
      </connectors>
-->
      <acceptors>

         <!-- useEpoll means: it will use Netty epoll if you are on a system (Linux) that supports it -->
         <!-- amqpCredits: The number of credits sent to AMQP producers -->
         <!-- amqpLowCredits: The server will send the # credits specified at amqpCredits at this low mark -->

         <!-- Note: If an acceptor needs to be compatible with HornetQ and/or Artemis 1.x clients add
                    "anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic." to the acceptor url.
                    See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-1644 for more information. -->

<!--
         <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300</acceptor>


         <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://0.0.0.0:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300</acceptor>


         <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>


         <acceptor name="hornetq">tcp://0.0.0.0:5445?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>


         <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://0.0.0.0:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
-->
         <acceptor name="netty-acceptor">tcp://localhost:61616</acceptor>
         <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://0.0.0.0:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true;sslEnabled=true;keyStorePath=/home/nik/Scrivania/javaCert3/broker_ks.p12;keyStorePassword=qwerty;trustStorePath=/home/nik/Scrivania/javaCert3/broker_ts.p12;trustStorePassword=qwerty;needClientAuth=false</acceptor>
      </acceptors>


      <security-settings>
         <security-setting match="#">
            <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="consume" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="browse" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="send" roles="amq"/>
            <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
            <permission type="manage" roles="amq"/>
         </security-setting>
      </security-settings>

      <address-settings>
         <!-- if you define auto-create on certain queues, management has to be auto-create -->
         <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>
         <!--default for catch all-->
         <address-setting match="#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>
      </address-settings>

      <addresses>
         <address name="DLQ">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="DLQ" />
            </anycast>
         </address>
         <address name="ExpiryQueue">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
            </anycast>
         </address>

      </addresses>


      <!-- Uncomment the following if you want to use the Standard LoggingActiveMQServerPlugin pluging to log in events
      <broker-plugins>
         <broker-plugin class-name="org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.plugin.impl.LoggingActiveMQServerPlugin">
            <property key="LOG_ALL_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_CONNECTION_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_SESSION_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_CONSUMER_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_DELIVERING_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_SENDING_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_INTERNAL_EVENTS" value="true"/>
         </broker-plugin>
      </broker-plugins>
      -->

   </core>
</configuration>
```

`login.config` contains

```
activemq {
   org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.PropertiesLoginModule required
       debug=false
       reload=true
       org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.user="artemis-users.properties"
       org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.role="artemis-roles.properties";
};

activemq-cert {
   org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.TextFileCertificateLoginModule required
       debug=true
       org.apache.activemq.jaas.textfiledn.user="cert-users.properties"
       org.apache.activemq.jaas.textfiledn.role="cert-roles.properties";
};
```

`cert-roles.properties` and `cert-users.properties` are equal to this [ssl dual authentication example](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/master/examples/features/standard/ssl-enabled-dual-authentication/src/main/resources/activemq/server0)

Finally I use `mosquitto_pub` to publish a message.

```
mosquitto_pub --cert client_cert.pem --key client_keypair.pem -h nik-VirtualBox -t "test" -m "message" -p 1883
```

I obtain:

```
Error: The connection was lost
```

On the Artemis log I see:

```
AMQ221053: Disallowing use of vulnerable protocol 'SSLv2Hello' on acceptor 'mqtt'.
AMQ224088: Timeout (10 seconds) while handshaking with /127.0.0.1:45912 has occurred.
```

What am I doing wrong? Certificates should be correct.

Comment: Can you paste your `bootstrap.xml` as well?

Comment: If the client has improper connection details about broker like port, certificates this error will occur. In my case, I tried to connect from Paho client where I gave 'tcp' instead of 'ssl' in URL

Answer (score 2):

The [`mosquitto_pub`](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto_pub-1.html) documentation contains this:

> **mosquitto_pub** supports TLS encrypted connections. It is strongly recommended that you use an encrypted connection for anything more than the most basic setup.
>
> To enable TLS connections when using x509 certificates, one of either `--cafile` or `--capath` must be provided as an option.
>
> To enable TLS connections when using TLS-PSK, you must use the `--psk` and the `--psk-identity` options.
>
> ...
>
> `--cafile`
>
> Define the path to a file containing PEM encoded CA certificates that are trusted. Used to enable SSL communication.
>
> See also `--capath`
>
> `--capath`
>
> Define the path to a directory containing PEM encoded CA certificates that are trusted. Used to enable SSL communication.
>
> For `--capath` to work correctly, the certificate files must have ".crt" as the file ending and you must run "openssl rehash " each time you add/remove a certificate.
>
> See also `--cafile`

Since you aren't defining either `--cafile` or `--capath` it looks to me like `mosquitto_pub` isn't even trying to use SSL/TLS to connect. The error message from the broker indicates this as well.

Comment: I did other tests, and I totally made a mistake, with ActiveMQ I made a wrong tcp port, it doesn't work, thanks, I check more carefully

Answer (score 1):

I made a mistake, checking carefully I realized that I had created the certificates with an error.

I rerun the procedure to create the certificates, but this time using openssl and then importing them into the keystore and the truststore.

Signing them both with the CA

Server

```
openssl genrsa -out ca.key 2048
openssl req -new -x509 -days 1826 -key ca.key -out ca.crt
openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
openssl req -new -out server.csr -key server.key
openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -days 360
```

Client

```
openssl genrsa -out client.key 2048
openssl req -new -out client.csr -key client.key
openssl x509 -req -in client.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out client.crt -days 360
```

Creation of keystore and truststore

```
keytool -import -file ca.crt -alias myCA -keystore server.ts
openssl pkcs12 -export -in server.crt -inkey server.key -out serverStore.p12 -CAfile ca.crt
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore serverStore.p12 -destkeystore server.ks -srcstoretype pkcs12
```

So it worked
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you clarify what the error actually was and what you did to resolve it?